# Is there a specific way to achieve the below scenarios in JMeter ? if yes how?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

Can someone guide how can I achieve below scenarios via JMeter

1.Check if system is able to process 1,00,000 random searches per hour

2.Check if system can accept 1,00,000 transaction's per minute- this is more like form submissions

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to implement your test scenarios (search and submitting forms) using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers

The HTTP Request samplers can be:

1. Recorded using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)
2. Recorded using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium)
3. Created manually basing on your application/endpoint specifications

Once you have test project skeleton and perform necessary [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of dynamic values and [parameterization](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) of dynamic parameters like usernames you can start defining the workload, i.e. see [Building a Web Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html) user manual chapter

Add as many virtual users as needed, run your test and see whether your application can handle the anticipated load.

Suggested scenario:

1. Increase the load gradually, i.e. start with 1 user and increment the number of users till the projected amount
2. Look at [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond) chart and [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime) chart. On well-behaved system the throughput (number of requests per second) should increase as the number of users increase.
3. If you detect the point when you increase the load but the throughput doesn't increase - it means that the system reached the maximum performance. If it is sufficient - you can report the test as passed, otherwise you will need to investigate the root cause and either report or fix it if you're capable of doing this.

Comment: Is it recommended to go for distributed load testing in this case since load is high ?